# Solve $e^x + e^y = 20$ for $y$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, exponential-function

I have an equation $e^x + e^y = 20$,where $e^x=\exp(x)$ and would like to express $y$ from this:
$$e^y = 20 - e^x \\\ln(e^y) = \ln(20-e^x) \\ y = \frac{\ln(20)}{\ln(e^x)} \\ y =\frac{ \ln(20)}{x}.$$
Is this okay?

Comment: I've rolled back to your initial suggested solution, because otherwise it looks weird if the answers are identical to the question.

Comment: that's fine @ArnaudD.

Answer (score 2):

$$\ln(a-b) \ne \frac{\ln(a)}{\ln(b)}$$

Comment: oh, I made a mistake there. Is there any way to separate this?

Comment: see edit in my answer

Answer (score 1):

$e^x+e^y=20$

$e^y=20-e^x$

$y=\ln(20-e^x)$

Edit:

If you really want to separate $\ln(20-e^x)$

then you can write it as $\ln(20)+\ln(1-\frac {e^x}{20})$,but that does not add any value to the result.

Comment: thank you, I just fixed it

Answer (score 1):

$$e^y=20-e^x$$
$$\ln(e^y)=\ln(20-e^x)$$
$$y=\ln(20-e^x)$$